# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am getting the following error when I call my webservice method.

```
Origin http://localhost:4165 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

When referring net I am getting solution like add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
I dont know where to add this. 
My script is :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post", dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:63384/ListWebService.asmx/HelloWorld", success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }, error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

And my webservice method is :

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello User";
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question. Just add the following to your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Also if you dont want it to be set up globally, then you can add it to your action method alone as below:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return "Hello User";
}
```

Comment: The `web.config` solution work like a charm. You can also write the domain of the requester instead of `*` to increase security.

Comment: But the second part of the solution (allowing access for only a specific method) doesn't work. It's because the request can't pass through `web.config` so it won't reach the method and therefore the method's allow-access is useless.

Comment: It will work and I have implemented it in my solution and so only gave as answer here.

Comment: Maybe without any `web.config` available to prevent the request from reaching the method?

Comment: You dont need to give any httpProtocol in web.config and this will then work.

Comment: Idk if it's a new update or what, but it appears that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header name now needs to be a value in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers". For example:

`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>`
`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />`

I kind of feel like the Chrome team is out to make this as difficult as possible... maybe so you use their tools or something.