# Ajax call from LocalHost to same domain MVC Controller during using KendoDataSource

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to access data from an MVC controller that is on an IIS Server located within my domain. I'm getting this error

```
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 Origin 'http://localhost:22205' is therefore not allowed access. "
```

**Here is my ajax call:**

```js
binDropDownDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
  autobind: false,
  serverFiltering: true,
  dataType: "json",
  crossDomain: true,
  transport: {
    read: {
      cache: false,
      //url: "/LogisticsWebApp/Requisitions/GetBins", This works if unremarked
      url: "https://www.MyDomain.com/LogisticsWebApp/requisitions/getsites",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      data: function () {
        {
          siteCode: viewModel.site.SiteCode,
          shopCode: viewModel.binShopBlock.ShopCode
        };
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Here is my controller:**

```cs
public JsonResult GetBins(string siteCode, string shopCode)
{
    var lookups = new Lookups();
    var data = lookups.GetBins(siteCode,shopCode);
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I want to be able to use an application as my data layer but need to be able to develop against it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174435/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @alan This comment is unrelated to your issue but is your `data` property correct? I keep wondering what that function is supposed to do since it does not return anything...

Comment: @Groyoh, The data function is for passing the parameters. I haven't yet figured out the difference between that and the Parameter Map function, they both seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it your for this particular method, you might change your `GetBins` action to:

```
public JsonResult GetBins(string siteCode, string shopCode)
{
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    var lookups = new Lookups();
    var data = lookups.GetBins(siteCode,shopCode);
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Edit**

If you need to do that from a method that is not in the controller you must use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: ,I tried this but am getting a red squiggly under "context" saying I'm missing an assembly or reference. Do you know which ones?

Comment: It seems that I made a mistake in my answer. I've edited it. If you still can't find `HttpContext`, try to import `System.Web.HttpContext` if you are in a class or `System.Web.HttpContextBase` if you are in a controller. If it still doesn't work, check that you properly reference the `System.Web.dll` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Add header **("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")** as well as header **("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")**

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```